# Given a simple polygon P, consisting of n vertices, and Set S Of k points, determine if each of the polygon vertices are covered by some point from S

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a simple polygon P, consisting of n vertices, and Set S Of k points, determine if each of the polygon vertices are covered by some point from S.

My best solution was to check for every P vertex if there exist such point in S - total complexity of O(n*k). I belive there should be a more efficient solution. any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether P is a polygon or not seems to be irrelevant. So the generalized question becomes: Given 2 sets of points A (with a points) and B (with b points), find out whether A is a subset of B or not?

The simple solution is O(a * b) but you can also get O(a + b) by doing some preprocessing.

1. Put all the points of B in a hash map with the x-coordinate as key and a hash set with the y-coordinates as values (`Map<Number,Set<Number>>`). This lets you query whether a point (x, y) is in B in O(1): `map.containsKey(x) && map.get(x).contains(y)`.
2. Go through all the points of A and check whether the point is in B using the datastructure created above.

Step 1 is O(b) and Step 2 is O(a) which gives O(a + b).